# There is no import of NPM package. How is it being used?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, video.js

[`mediacms-vjs-plugin`](https://github.com/mediacms-io/mediacms/tree/main/frontend/packages/vjs-plugin) is a custom plugin for Video.js.

The `MediaCmsVjsPlugin.js` source file starts with:

```js
import { version as VERSION } from '../package.json';

import 'mediacms-vjs-plugin-font-icons/dist/mediacms-vjs-icons.css';
import './styles.scss';
```

As can be seen, there is no `import` of `videojs`. However, `videojs` is being used all over the code like:

```js
function generatePlugin() {
    const videojsComponent = videojs.getComponent('Component');
    const videojsClickableComponent = videojs.getComponent('ClickableComponent');
    const videojsComponentButton = videojs.getComponent('Button');

    const __MediaCMSComponent__ = videojs.extend(videojsComponent, {
```

How is it possible to use `videojs` without importing it first?

Its `package.json` file specifies `videojs` as a *peer dependency*:

```json
  "peerDependencies": {
    "video.js": "^7.12.3"
  },
```

Could it be that whenever there is a *peer dependency*, we don't have to import it explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a plugin, It's likely written on the assumption that you already have videojs in your project and that you're importing it somewhere, before importing the plugin.